# How do you calculate number percent between 2 arbitrary numbers

Tags: percentages

So for example, using a real example I'm faced with

The maximum range is 0.50 and the minimum range is 0.025. Say I have a number 0.33. At what percent is it in that range.

Google searching reveals many dozens of topics discussing a maximum range between 0 and a max number whee you divide the 2 numbers to get the percent but in the case here it's not 0 it's an arbitrary number as the minimum.

Any help here would be great, thanks!

Comment: Subtract $x_{min}=0.025$ from all the other numbers, and the problem will be reduced to the one you found how to solve. $$ $$ $x_{max}=0.5-0.025$ and $x=0.33-0.025$. Now find ther percentage as $\frac{x}{x_{max}} \cdot 100$ as usual

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply subtract the lower number, then divide by the difference between the two numbers.

$$100\left(\frac{x-m}{M-m}\right)\%$$

The hundred multiplication is to fix the units.

---

In your example, you should get $100\frac{0.33-0.025}{0.5-0.025} \approx 64.2\%. $

Comment: Ah, thank you very much, this is perfect and so much simpler than I might have anticipated!